# Data Binding in UWP

Tags: data-binding, uwp

Since I am new to UWP.
I need to bind a property in MainPage.Cs file to Mainpage.xaml and Display the data.
Please find the below code.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
  public string ButtonText { get ; set ; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        ButtonText = "Blue";
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Mainpage.Xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}" />
</Grid>
```

The  button content is not displayed in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is caused by missing DataContext. Every binding consists of **a binding target** and **a binding source**. Typically, the target is a property of a control or other UI element, and the source is a property of a class instance (a data model, or a view model). DataContext is the place where the binding markup extension will find its source. You could add the following code into the code behind:

```
        ButtonText = "Blue";
        this.InitializeComponent();
        //set the data context as itself.
        this.DataContext = this;
```

Another choice is that you could use x:bind markup extension. It will consider the code-behind as the DataContext automatically.

It looks like this:

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
     <!-- don't need to change code in code-behind -->
    <Button Content="{x:Bind ButtonText}" />
</Grid>
```

You could refer to this document for more information about Data Binding: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) and [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).